# How to implement time event scheduler in python?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, scheduling

In python how to implement a thread which runs in the background (may be when the module loads) and calls the function every minute Monday to Friday 10 AM to 3 PM. For example the function should be called at:

10:01 AM
10:02 AM
10:03 AM
.
.
2:59 PM

Any pointers?

Environment: Django

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is a server application, which only reacts to external events.

You should use a scheduler like **cron** to create events that call your django application, either calling a management subcommand or doing an HTTP request on some special page.

Comment: GAE does this with Task Queues (experimental) and Cron hooks

Answer (score 2):

The [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=schedule#timer-objects) class is convenient to do such tasks. But you have to compute interval yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make a command http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands and then cron it.

Answer (score -1):

Note sure how django affects threads (unless you're using App Engine where you can't do low level such), but once your thread is running you can continuously check timestamps:

```
from datetime import time
from datetime import date
time_delta = 60
while True:
    end_time = time.time() + time_delta
    while time.time() < end_time:
        time.sleep(1)
    if date.today().weekday() in range(1,5):
        #do something baby
```

Not tested, so take it for a spin first.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an article about scheduling tasks in cron from google code.

[Scheduling Tasks with Cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#The_Schedule_Format)

Comment: Do you this it's OK to use GTK in web environment?