# How do I check if it's Monday to Friday and the time is between 10 AM to 3 PM?

Tags: python, datetime

In python how do I check if its a weekday (Monday - Friday) and the time is between 10 AM to 3 PM?

Comment: your previous question has an answer containing code that you're asking here for! not to mention that you're just duplicating that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902338/how-to-implement-time-event-scheduler-in-python

Comment: Sorry but the earlier solution was voted -ve

Comment: so what? does it somehow stop code from running?

Comment: @SilentGhost, to be fair, I can't see that the question you mention has any code that addresses the time part of the question, only the date.  And crudely at that.  And that question looked to be more focused on how to do the background work, while this is actually a better, more focused question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now() 
# => datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 15, 13, 50, 35, 833175)

# check if weekday is 1..5
>>> d.isoweekday() in range(1, 6)
True

# check if hour is 10..15
>>> d.hour in range(10, 15)
True

# check if minute is 30
>>> d.minute==30
False
```

Comment: The hour check should be `d.hour in range(10, 15)`.  If the hour equals 15, it's past 3 PM, so we shouldn't include 15 in the range of allowed hours.

Comment: How do we go if the time range is 9:30 AM to 3:30 PM?

Comment: For checking in range 9.30AM to 3.30PM: d.hour*60+d.minute in range(9*60+30, 15*60+30)

Comment: isoweekday is actually a function so it needs to be isoweekday()

Comment: @DanielPatz, wow, a three year old typo - thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 15, 12, 45, 33, 781000)
>>> now.isoweekday()
2        # Tuesday
```

time between 10 a.m. and 3 p.m. is right there as well

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

The documentation states that `date.weekday()` returns the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. So this code will work:

`import datetime
 # Hours must be 24 hour clock times 
 def is_weekday_and_time_in_range(date, start_hour, end_hour):
    return date.weekday() < 5 and date.hour in range(start_hour, end_hour)
 today = datetime.datetime.now()
 is_weekday_and_time_in_range(today, 10, 15)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532308/is-it-possible-to-check-day-and-timestamp-between-two-different-days-with-time-s