# Python and check if current datetime is in specific range

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907196/how-do-i-check-if-its-monday-to-friday-and-the-time-is-between-10-am-to-3-pm), but i want to specify the start date and end date by actual weekday names and times.  For example, I want to check if the current datetime (datetime.datetime.now()) is in between Tuesday at 4:30pm and Thursday at 11:45am.  This would update weekly so it has to be by Tuesday/Thursday mentality.

I have thought about how to do the weekdays (but i don't know how to wrap the time part into it):

```
TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()

if TimeNow.weekday() >= 1 and TimeNow.weekday() <= 3:
    #runcodehere
```

Any thoughts on how i would do this?

Comment: Have you tried something with `and`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neatest way is to use the amount of minutes elapsed in a week:

```
def mins_in_week(day, hour, minute):
    return day * 24 * 60 + hour * 60 + minute

if (mins_in_week(1, 16, 30) < 
    mins_in_week(TimeNow.weekday(), TimeNow.hour, TimeNow.minute) < 
    mins_in_week(3, 11, 45)):
    ....
```

Comment: i was thinking of `isoweekday()`

Comment: I also made changed "min" to "minute" to avoid keyword being utilized.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very neat but something like this should work:

```
TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()

if (TimeNow.weekday() == 1 and ((TimeNow.hour() == 4 and TimeNow.minute >= 30) or TimeNow.hour > 4)) or (TimeNow.weekday() == 2) or (TimeNow.weekday() == 3 and (TimeNow.hour() < 11 or (TimeNow.hour() == 11 and TimeNow.minute <= 45)):
     #runcodehere
```

Comment: What about Tuesday, 5pm ? A test is missing on the current hour to take account of minutes : `if (TimeNow.weekday() == 1 and (TimeNow.hour > 4 or (TimeNow.hour == 4 and TimeNow.minute >= 30)) or TimeNow.weekday() > 1) and (TimeNow.weekday() == 3 and (TimeNow.hour > 11 or (TimeNow.hour == 11 and TimeNow.minute <= 45)) or TimeNow.weekday() < 3) :`

Comment: Thanks, I had just noticed the same thing. Have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `and` and `or`, and have different conditions for each day:

```
import datetime

TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()

day_now = TimeNow.weekday()
time_now = TimeNow.hour*60 + TimeNow.minute

if (day_now == 1 and time_now > 990) or (day_now == 2) or (day_now == 3 and time_now < 705):
    # do something
```

Comment: `weekday()` for Thurs is 4, not 3

Comment: The docs beg to differ: "[Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)". Maybe you're thinking of `isoweekday()`?

Comment: ah yes, I am thinking of `isoweekday()`